# How to remove the decimal .00 from the default highcharts configuration?

Tags: javascript, graph, frontend, highcharts

I'm using a integer sequence of values in highcharts, but it's adding .00 after each result. Any tips on how to solve that?

[image: Ex: 353.00 should be 353]

You can see the code i'm using here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/20425/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument for `Highcharts.numberFormat` specifies how many decimals you want. This should work:

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
```

[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Math.round` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You were only missing one parameter for the `.numberFormat()` method.  Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/20477/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is how your data look like -

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 353.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                        ^^^^^                                ^^^
```

and it does not look like a sequence of integers (only).

But, if it were really a sequence of integers as follows -

> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 353, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

then you could just do -

```
formatter: function() {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' + this.y;
}
```

and Highcharts would never add that ".00".